# Yii2 <a> / <button> link issues in Android browser

Tags: android, html, yii2

A bit of an odd one here. (I haven't tested it on an iPhone, but the issue may appear there also)

When clicking certain links on an Android phone, the "open with" popup appears. This is a pretty poor experience. I can't work out why it is happening for some links and not others.

The issue can be seen on: http://coursetracker.com.au/university

The issue can be seen when progressing forward on this page, by either searching and clicking [continue] or clicking a university. On a web browser there is no issues, the user continues forward, it only seems to be on a mobile.

The examples on this page are the  element, it also happens on  elements. I have tried changing links to "_self" with no luck.

Any help or thoughts would be great. Thanks!